# CUDA - STL vector corrupt when passed to a class compiled with nvcc

Tags: c++, vector, stl, cuda

### SOLVED

I found the problem. I forced nvcc to optimize even though i set the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug. So nvcc optimized the vector and g++ not.

### Question

I've a weird behavior that I'm not sure how to explain. Basically, I've a class that encapsulate all the things that I want to do with CUDA. But the error has nothing with CUDA API. I'll summarize it a snippet of code.

```
//Foo.cuh
class Foo{
    void updateData(const std::vector<Bar> &_bars);
    // Other methods related to CUDA stuff
};

//Foo.cu
void Foo::updateData(const std::vector<Bar> &_bars){
    std::cout << "Size of vector: " << _bars.size() << std::endl;   
    // Do thing with data, cudamalloc and so on...    
}

// main.cpp
Foo foo;
std::vector<Bar> bars = /*Something of size 125*/;
std::cout << "Size of vector: " << bars.size() << std::endl;    
foo.updateData(bars);
```

Then, if I run the code, the first output throw `Size of vector: 125` And the second `Size of vector: 14710694641059515977`

I'm not reaching any CUDA code, it's only a problem passing the stl vector to a class that manage CUDA code. As far as I concern, .cpp code is compiled with g++ and .cu code with nvcc. Could it be related to that?

Any answer is appreciated. Thanks you!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I found the problem. I forced nvcc to optimize even though i set the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug. So nvcc optimized the vector and g++ not.

Comment: Please add an answer to your question not a solved edit. And FYI nvcc *is* GCC in this example, the only difference is there compiler options. Nvcc isn't a compiler, it just steers compilation using GCC or the device compiler depending on the code

Comment: Oh, I'll modify it. And thank you for the notation. I thought that nvcc was a different compiler but based on gcc

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I forced nvcc to optimize, setting -O2, even though I set the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug. So nvcc optimized the vector and g++ not.